# list all the objects in sql server which contains a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find all the processes / objects present in the database, which contains specific column of 1 table.How to get that list?

Here Processes / Objects can be sp, view,functions,trigger,jobs.

Comment: Rename it and see what breaks?

Comment: On 2 of the replies, you state the suggested answer is not working. What errors do you get? What isn't working? Could you provide some more details of what it is you are after, which might assist us to help you better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that?

```
SELECT Name
FROM Sys.Objects O INNER JOIN Sys.sql_modules M
ON O.object_id = M.object_id
WHERE M.definition LIKE CONCAT('% Col', CHAR(10), '%')
      OR
      M.definition  LIKE '% Col %';
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6ecc30ec9f42916e48bdb32ad1509d90)**

Note that this won't be 100% the solution, because it depends on the `definition` column, maybe you have eg: `SELECT [Col]` or `SELECT [dbo].[T].[Col]`

Comment: @BTSQL Check the demo

Answer (score 1):

For tables on the database that contain a specific column use:

```
 USE YOURDB

 SELECT T.name, C.name
 FROM sys.tables T
 LEFT JOIN sys.columns C
 ON T.object_id = C.object_id
 WHERE C.name LIKE '%search string%'
```

To list all objects that contain a keyword use:

```
 SELECT definition, name, type
 FROM sys.objects o
 JOIN sys.sql_modules m on m.object_id = o.object_id
 WHERE
 definition LIKE '%search string%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this two sys tables that might help you(Oracle SQL):

```
select * from SYS.ALL_DEPENDENCIES;

select * from SYS.ALL_SOURCE
where TEXT like '%YOUR_COLUMN%';
```

Or maybe this will help(SQL Server):

```
SELECT
  so.id,
  so.name,
  sc.text
FROM syscomments sc
INNER JOIN sysobjects so
  ON so.id = sc.id
```

Comment: The question tagged with `SQL Server` tag not `Oracle`

Comment: getting invalid object nameerror for  :- sys.all_source and sys.all_dependencies tables

Comment: My mistake,I am sorry, I have added a SQL Server  proposition.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
    FROM Sys.Objects O INNER JOIN
    sys.columns C on O.object_id = c.object_id
    where C.name='trip_name'
```